# Braverman-Gaitsgory definition of local acyclicity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

In the Appendix B of the published version of ‘Geometric Eisenstein Series’ (but not found in the arXiv version), Braverman and Gaitsgory compare their notion of local acyclicity with Deligne’s. I have two questions about it.

1. Their Definition B.1 was made by Deligne for finite coefficients, but is stated here for ℓ-adic sheaves.  What is meant by $R\Gamma(Y_{y,t},\mathcal S)$? Here $Y_{y,t}$ is a geometric fiber of a map of strict henselizations, and as $Y_{y,t}$ is far from of finite type over the base field, if $\mathcal S$ is represented by a $\mathbf{Z}_\ell$ sheaf $\mathcal S_0$, I don’t know that $R\Gamma(Y_{y,t},\mathcal S_0\otimes^L \mathbf{Z}/\ell\mathbf{Z})$ is finite, so I don’t know how to define $R\Gamma$ on (a bounded derived category of) $\mathbf{Z}_\ell$-sheaves on $Y_{y,t}$ (let alone on $\mathbf{Q}_\ell$-sheaves).
2. In the proof of Theorem B.2 the authors claim that Definition B.1 is equivalent to the map
   $$\mathcal S\otimes f^*(i_*(\mathcal L))\to\tilde i_*(\tilde i^*(\mathcal S)\otimes f^{0*}(\mathcal L))$$
   being an isomorphism for every choice of $i$ and $\mathcal L$ (this equation is also labeled B.1 in the paper). Here $i:S^0\hookrightarrow S$ is the immersion of a smooth locally closed subvariety of a smooth variety $S$, $\mathcal L$ is a lisse sheaf on $S$, $\tilde i:Y^0\to Y$ is the base change of $i$ and $f^0:Y^0\to S^0$ is the restriction of a map $f:Y\to S$. This reminds me of Lemma 7.6.1 and Theorem 7.6.9 of Lei Fu’s book on étale cohomology, but there, the map $i$ needs to be allowed to be a geometric point. Even for finite coefficients, does anyone have a reference for this (supposedly ‘easy to see’) claim?

Thanks for any suggestions, references, or help you may have!

Comment: 1. Yes, this definition is sloppy and it's not clear what is intended. // 2. This equivalence is certainly not "easy to see" and actually might be false - I discussed this with Luc Illusie and Weizhe Zheng, probably the world experts on local acyclicity, and neither of them could see why this is true. // There IS a good definition of (U)LAness with Q_ell-coefficients, but it's NOT the definition proposed by BG. Please email me if you'd like to discuss further!!